# How can i report how much size of the file have downloaded so far out of the whole file size?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void DownloadFile()
        {
            if (_downloadUrls.Any())
            {
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += client_DownloadProgressChanged;
                client.DownloadFileCompleted += client_DownloadFileCompleted;

                var url = _downloadUrls.Dequeue();
                string startTag = "animated/";
                string endTag = "/infra";

                int index = url.IndexOf(startTag);
                int index1 = url.IndexOf(endTag);

                string fname = url.Substring(index + 9, index1 - index - 9);

                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                req.Method = "HEAD";
                HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
                long len = resp.ContentLength;

                client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), @"C:\Temp\tempframes\" + fname + ".gif");

                lastDownloadedFile = @"C:\Temp\tempframes\" + fname + ".gif";
                label1.Text = url;
                return;
            }

            // End of the download
            btnStart.Text = "Download Complete";
        }

        private void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                // handle error scenario
                throw e.Error;
            }
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                // handle cancelled scenario
            }

            Image img = new Bitmap(lastDownloadedFile);
            Image[] frames = GetFramesFromAnimatedGIF(img);
            foreach(Image image in frames)
            {
                countFrames++;
                image.Save(@"C:\Temp\tempframes\" + countFrames + ".gif");
            }

            DownloadFile();
        }

        void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
            double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
            double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
            pBarFileProgress.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
        }
```

With the HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse i can get the file size.
Now i want whil it's downloading the file to report to a label the number of bytes downloaded so far out of the long len size.

For example on label1 to see: 1024kb/50mb or something like that not sure in what size units to show it but this is the idea.
And the same thing to do on another label and displat the download speed of the current file download.

Comment: I don't understand, why can't you simply update the label text from within the client_DownloadProgressChanged method as you do for the progress bar value?

Comment: The problem is to know the size of the stream being downloaded, which is not always set in the HttpWebResponse. If you are also managing the server, you may insert a HttpHeader with the filesize in the response.